# Repeat calls inside Ruby partial

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial, middleman

I'm new to Ruby, so this may be straight forward. I have a partial which I want to essentially populate a list.

Here's my partial (.erb) code:

```
<ul>
  <% if locals.has_key? :sermon_commentary %>
    <li><i class="material-icons">link</i><a href="<%= sermon_commentary %>">Matthew Henry's Commentary on <%= sermon_passage %></a></li>
  <% end %>
  <% if locals.has_key? :sermon_passage_lookup %>
    <li><i class="material-icons">link</i><a href="<%= sermon_passage_lookup %>"><%= sermon_passage %> on Bible Gateway</a></li>
  <% end %>
  <% if locals.has_key? :sermon_audio_download %>
    <li><i class="material-icons">music_note</i><a href="/audio/<%= sermon_audio_download %>" download="/audio/<%= sermon_audio_download %>">Download this sermon (MP3 ~5mb)</a></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And here's how I'm calling it in a .html.erb file:

```
  :sermon_commentary => "https://www.biblegateway.com/resources/matthew-henry/Luke",
  :sermon_passage_lookup => "https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+4%3A14-21&version=NIV",
  :sermon_audio_download => "FUSE_7th_August.mp3",
  :sermon_video => "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/VzOYe8nUCS4?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0"
```

However with the current code above, if I want *multiple* list items (say, a second 'sermon_passage_lookup' list item, it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. I think I need a

```
[something].each do |something|
```

But I'm not sure how to structure it. Thanks :)

EDIT: Implementing Taryn's fix

Thanks for all your help so far, Taryn. I now see the distinct differences between the hash and the array. I've set my partial template as per your suggestion:

```
<ul>
  <% if locals.has_key? :sermon_links %>
    <% sermon_links.each do |link| %>
      <li>
        <i class="material-icon‌​s"><%= link[:icon] %></i>
        <a href="<%= link[:hyperlink] %>"><%= link[:link_label] %></a>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And I'm using it as such:

```
:sermon_links => [
   { :icon => "link", :hyperlink => "http://www.facebook.com/", :link_label => "Testing" },
   { :icon => "link", :hyperlink => "http://google.com/", :link_label => "Testing2" }
 ]
```

Unfortunately I'm getting errors. Looks like the 'link' hash isn't being recognised? Here's what Chrome throws at me:

`NameError at /resources/sermons/the-fifth-act/fuse-14-08-16.html
undefined local variable or method 'icon' for #<Middleman::Application:0x70168621815860>`

Comment: `undefined local variable or method 'icon'` This sounds like you've got the word `icon` instead of `:icon` somewhere... or something similar. Ruby expects that to be an actual variable name, but you probably mean something different eg the symbol. Perhaps you've got `link[icon]` where you should have `link[:icon]` ?

Comment: Sure thing, thanks Taryn. Seems to be rendering now, but with yet another quirk; with `<i class="material-icons"><%=link[:icon]%></i>` and `{ :icon => "link", :hyperlink => "http://www.facebook.com/", :link_label => "Beau" },` I should be seeing this as HTML output: `<i class="material-icons">link</i>` however I'm getting a bunch if random characters in the DOM: `<i class="material-icon&zwnj;&#8203;s">link</i>` Any idea as to why this may be happening? Thanks again for all your help Taryn. You've been a life saver!

Comment: New bugs should be put in a new question... also code-formatting in comments is truly dreadful and impossible to read :P
Can you make a new question - you can then post the link here so I see it in my inbox :)

Comment: Done :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384574/unexpected-characters-injected-in-dom-inside-ruby-partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you make sure you pass in the `sermon_passage_lookups` as an array (even if there's one item) then you can call each on them just as you mention eg:

```
<% if locals.has_key? :sermon_passage_lookups %>
  <% sermon_passage_lookups.each do |sermon_passage_lookup| %>
    <li><i class="material-icons">link</i><a href="<%= sermon_passage_lookup %>"><%= sermon_passage %> on Bible Gateway</a></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

EDIT

a variation on your example given in the comments below:

Firstly the main `.erb` template: I think you don't need the redundant word `:link` here -> just put each link-set into the main array. Also you don't need the extra array around the link-hash eg all you need is:

```
:sermon_links => [
   { :icon => "link", :hyperlink => "http://www.facebook‌​.com/", :link_label => "Testing" },
   {:icon => "link2", :hyperlink => "http://google.com/", :link_label => "Testing2"} ]
```

ie include just the data you need, and nothing you don't.

This is a *hash* with the key of `sermon_links` and the *value* is an array.
The array contains hashes - each one corresponding to the link-data you need to list.

Then, your partial template will need to access these hashes from the `sermon_links` array. Your example in the comments is treating the values of the hash as though they are variable-name (eg `<%= icon %>`) but that won't work... the only variable is named `sermon_links` which you then use `each` to turn each value into a single hash which you are naming `link`, so you need to reference `link` as a hash to get the icon out of it... like this:

```
<ul>
  <% if locals.has_key? :sermon_links %>
    <!-- at this point we have the full `sermon_links` -->
    <% sermon_links.each do |link| %>
      <!-- now we have a single `link` from the set eg
         - { :icon => "link",
             :hyperlink => "http://www.facebook‌​.com/",
             :link_label => "Testing" } -->
      <li>
        <i class="material-icon‌​s"><%= link[:icon] %></i>
        <a href="<%= link[:hyperlink] %>"><%= link[:link_label] %></a>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Taryn. When I attempt the following

`:sermon_passage_lookups {
    :sermon_passage_lookup => "test",
    :sermon_passage_lookup => "test",
    :sermon_passage_lookup => "test",
  }`
I get errors. No dice.

Comment: That's because the above fragment is not proper ruby... neither a hash nor an array. you'd need: `:sermon_passage_loo‌​kups => [ {:sermon_passage_look‌​up => "test1"}, {:sermon_passage_look‌​up => "test2"}, {:sermon_passage_look‌​up => "test3"} ]` Which is an array contained three hashes.

Comment: (1/2)Thanks Taryn. As mentioned, I'm still a newbie at Ruby so I really appreciate all this amazing help! I wonder now if I can simplify my structure. I tried something like this but it resulted in errors:

`<ul>
  <% if locals.has_key? :sermon_links %>
    <% sermon_links.each do |link| %>
      <li><i class="material-icons"><%= icon %></i><a href="<%= hyperlink %>"><%= link_label %></a></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>`

Comment: (2/2)And my .erb file:
`:sermon_links => [
  {
    :link => [{
      :icon => "link",
      :hyperlink => "http://www.facebook.com/",
      :link_label => "Testing"
      }]
  }
]`

Comment: I'll edit my answer to add my variant of your answer

Comment: Thanks a bunch Taryn, I'll edit my original question with my updated response.

Comment: Hi Taryn - any further thoughts on the above? Thanks so much for your help so far :)