# Unexpected characters injected in DOM inside Ruby partial

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby partial controlling lists. It takes an attribute for an icon, label, and hyperlink. The icon generation is the part in question:

```
<i class="material-icons"><%=link[:icon]%></i>
```

I'm calling it as such:

```
{ :icon => "link", :hyperlink => "http://www.facebook.com/", :link_label => "Beau" }
```

The expected HTML output, in the above case (for the icon) should be:

```
<i class="material-icons">link</i>
```

However, some random characters are being inserted in the DOM which causes the icon to break:

```
<i class="material-icon&zwnj;&#8203;s">link</i>
```

I have no idea what's causing this. Any help would be appreciated :) thanks!

Comment: the code is settung you a so called [zero-width-no-joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner)  Did you copy the code? Maybe it was the "invisible" character you pastet in.

Comment: &#8203; - [zero-width-whitespace](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/tryit.asp?filename=8203)

Comment: I'd suggest re-typing the hash manually from scratch.

Comment: Yeah sometimes copy/paste means you get all kinds of "special" characters... best option is as Kris said - retype and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Great - thanks guys. A re-type solved the issue. Must have been some odd spacing or white space from when I copied the solution someone else helped me with. Thanks! :)